# How to make divs fit a bigger div but keep their size ratio?

Tags: html, css

I'm building the graphic aspect of a mancala game with HTML, CSS and Javascript (Though JS is iirelevant to this question). I managed to build the board, but my teacher wants the game so that the player will be able to enter the number of holes they want between 3 to 7. My problem is that the holes get weird looking when I remove or add holes (I want them to be circles!).

https://jsfiddle.net/kxdetz12/

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
    Mancala
</h1>
<div class="board">
    <div class='player1name'>  Player 1 </div>

    <div class="containerStore">
        <div class="storep1">
            <div class="label">
                0
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerStore">
        <div class="storep2">
            <div class="label">
                0
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="pit">
        </div>
        <div class="pit">
        </div>
        <div class="pit">
        </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>
        <div class="pit">  </div>

    </div>
    <div class='player2name'> Player 2 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand...

I took the fixed widths and heights off of the pits.  Then inserted a block in to each .pit using css.  Padding-top, surprisingly, is relative to the width of the element.

This is a handy trick for maintaining aspect ratios on responsive elements.

```
.pit {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 169, 77, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin: 5px; 
    border: 5px;
    border-radius: 100px; 
    border-style: inset; 
    border-color: saddlebrown;
}

.pit:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3q5ctjw0/